# Expandable recycler view

Tags: android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

Is there any way to make Amazon mobile application like "Menu" with nested expandable RecyclerView using java. I have been trying to replicate it but I don't know how to start designing the layout for it.

Anyone have any idea that how can I achive it?